# Poner a true el checkbox de un DataGridViewCheckBoxCell

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagrid

Cargo un DataGridView a través de una lista.

```
datagridview.DataSource = listaVariables;
```

Este DatagridView, está formado por una columna (la primera) que es del tipo DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.

Lo que quiero hacer es que, dependiendo de una propiedad de las variables de la lista, se active como marcado o no.

He probado a hacer esto:

```
datagridview.Rows[pos].Cell[0].Value = true; //pos es un entero que utilizo para recorrer las filas y pongo 0 en Cell porque es la primera columna la que tiene los CheckBox
```

y no hace nada, lo deja desmarcado.

He probado también a crear una celda del tipo DataGridViewCheckBoxCell iniciándola a true pero tampoco me funciona, me da un error de formato de la celda (System.FormatException: El valor con formato de la celda tiene un tipo erroneo):

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell dC = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell(true);
datagridview.Rows[pos].Cell[0] = dC;
```

En esta última prueba creo que la celda que creo (aunque no me deje asignarla) que tampoco me pondría el checkbox que contiene a true.

También he probado a hacer:

```
dataGridView.Rows[pos].SetValues(true); //Se supone que la primera celda de la fila la debería poner a true y no lo hace
```

y

```
var values = new bool[] { true };
dataGridView.Rows[pos].SetValues(values);
```

y sigo con el mismo resultado, no me muestra el checkbox activado.

La lista con la que cargo el datagrid la defino así:

```
List<PlacaVariableP> listaVariables;
```

El objeto Variable es el siguiente:

```
public class PlacaVariableP:IComparable
{
    public virtual long id_placavariable { get; set; }
    public virtual long idplaca { get; set; }
    public virtual string descripcion { get; set; }
    public virtual string unidades { get; set; }
    public virtual string idFichero { get; set; }

    public virtual int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        PlacaVariableP c = (PlacaVariableP)obj;
        return String.Compare(this.descripcion, c.descripcion, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    public virtual void toString(object obj)
    {
        obj.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muestra por favor la clase con la que llenas listavariables y tambien la definicion de esa variable

Comment: He añadido la clase variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que a la hora de trabajar con un DataGridView tienes dos formas de hacerlo:

1. Utilizando DataSource:

De esta forma estableces el contenido a mostrar en el DataGridView a través de la propiedad DataSource y ésta es la información que se muestra.

Si quieres realizar cambios debes realizarlos en el objeto que has establecido como DataSource y volver a asociárselo. No puedes modificar el contenido de las celdas directamente.

2. Manipulando filas y celdas:

Puedes rellenar el contenido añadiendo objetos DataGridViewRow a la colección Rows del DataGridView y estableciendo los valores de cada celda.

De esta forma sí que puedes manipular el contenido de las celdas directamente.

Por lo tanto si vas a usar DataSource los elementos contenidos en la lista que asocias al DataSource deberían tener una propiedad para establecer el valor de la columna de tipo check.

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
        dataGridView1.DataSource = listaVariables.Select(x =>
            new
            {
                columnaCheck = x.id_placavariable > 20,
                x.descripcion,
                x.id_placavariable,
                x.idFichero,
                x.idplaca,
                x.unidades
            }).ToList();
```

De esta forma los elementos del DataSource tendrán una propiedad (en el ejemplo `columnaCheck`) con el valor para la columna.

Comment: A la hora de cargar el datagridview si que lo hago a través del DataSource, pero la columna de los checkbox lo hago desde la parte gráfica del SharpDevelop. Según lo que dices llego a la siguiente conclusión, no lo puedo hacer asi???

Comment: No. O estableces todos los valores a de las celdas a través de un DataSource o modificando los valores directamente por código. Pero en un mismo DataGridView no puedes utilizar un sistema para unas celdas y otro para otras.

Comment: Ok, voy a probar lo que me dices, gracias

Comment: Asier, eso no es cierto. Se pueden tener en un mismo DataGridView columnas generadas en tiempo de diseño y a su vez cargar datos usando DataSource. No tiene mucha lógica, pero si es posible. De todas maneras, tu solución es buena y yo usaría un enfoque similar seguramente, pero sospecho que el problema del OP es otro...

Comment: Claro que puedes crear columnas en tiempo de diseño, pero si cargas los datos a través del DataSource deberás establecer el valor de la propiedad DataPropertyName de la columna para asociarlo a alguna propiedad de los objetos del DataSource. De esta forma las celdas se rellenarán con los datos de esta propiedad. Lo que no vas a poder es modificar directamente el Value de las celdas de esa columna.

Comment: Yo estaba convencido de que podía añadir por un lado, en la parte de diseño la columna de CheckBox y por otro lado el listado y hasta este punto me funcionaba todo, pero a partir de aquí... tengo que decir que la solución ha sido la de @AsierVillanueva. Muchas gracias

Comment: @AsierVillanueva no es necesario. Si quieres haz una prueba rápida, crea un datagridview y añadele una DataGridViewCheckColumn. Despues,en el código create una clase sencilla con una propiedad, crea una lista de esta clase y añade un par de datos. Asigna esta lista al DataGridView.Datasource. Verás como aparecen la columna del checkbox y la de la lista,y puedes perfectamente por código activar y desactivar el check sin problemas

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano me alegra de que lo hayas solucionado, la respuesta de Asier es perfecta y es la manera de trabajar con DatagridViews.Pero como lo estabas haciendo tambien debería funcionar en principio...

Comment: De todas maneras me gustaría saber (si al final se puede que creo que si) como se hace de la manera que estaba probando.

Comment: Cierto he estado haciendo alguna prueba y si la columna no está asociada a una propiedad del DataSource debería permitirte modificarla. El código que he utilizado para modificar el valor de una celda de tipo check es: `bool currentValue = (bool?) dataGridView1[0, 0].Value ?? false;` `dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = !currentValue;`

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias @AsierVillanueva por el interés y por la ayuda, así da gusto, de verdad

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn. Un ejemplo sencillo sería:

```
bool[] arr = new bool[3];
        arr[0] = true;
        arr[1] = false;
        arr[2] = true;


        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        col1.FalseValue = false;
        col1.TrueValue = true;

        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col1);

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(arr.Length-1);


        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell check = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0];
            if (arr[i] == true)
            {
                check.Value = check.TrueValue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Si no le funciona accediendo al `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` , por que crees que si lo hará accediendo a la columna?

Comment: Complemente un poco mas mi respuesta, de hecho escribí el código (Probado y funcionando) para que compare , y si es lo que necesita lo adapte a sus necesidades desde este punto.

Comment: Bueno, yo echo en falta algo como "tu código no funciona porque ____" y la solución es "_____". Efectivamente, tu código funciona, pero yo tambien tengo código accediendo a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` y funciona perfectamente :)

Comment: No era esa la intención. Solamente escribí un código para comparar y que espero pueda ayudarle a dar con el problema. No digo que esta sea la solución definitiva. Desde ahora pondré mas atención a mis respuestas.Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Lo primero, gracias por ayudar a los 2. A raíz de este código, lo que veo es que mi TrueValue y FalseValue estaban a null, rellenándolos así ya pone la propiedad Value a true, pero sigue sin marcar el checkbox, no creo que sea porque no se actualice el datagridview porque después de ponerlo a true lo actualizo llamando a datagridview.Update() y datagridview.Refresh().